# ResultTransformer with createSQLQuery forces no camelCase in entity fields

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I have an sql query as follows:

```
List<Employee> employees = getCurrentSession()
                    .createSQLQuery(
                            "select"
                                    + e.id as id,e.first_name as firstName,e.password as password
                                    + "from employee e,employee_role er,role r where e.employee_id=er.employee_id and er.role_id=r.role_id and r.name='ROLE_ADMIN' ")
                    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))
                    .list();
```

I have a property in the Employee called firstName, but when trying to run above dao in a unit test, I am getting the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find setter for firstname on class com.app.domain.Employee
```

I don't know where hibernate get from this firstname property ? I didn't right it in my query ?

any way the workaround was to change the property to firstname, and getters,setters too
but any ideas why hibernate is making such behavior, and how to avoid it, since I want to use camelCase in my domain, please advise.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use [addScalar(String columnAlias, Type type)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadoc/org/hibernate/SQLQuery.html#addScalar%28java.lang.String,%20org.hibernate.type.Type%29) to explicitly declare the column alias of your native SQL:

```java
getCurrentSession()
    .createSQLQuery( "select e.id as id,e.first_name as firstName,e.password as password from xxxxxx")
    .addScalar("id",StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER )
    .addScalar("firstName",StandardBasicTypes.STRING )
    .addScalar("password",StandardBasicTypes.STRING )
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))
    .list();
```

Comment: addScalar+select as in the query too ?

Comment: i think so , as only using `addScalar()` without `select as` will give me errors.

Answer (score 20):

For a simpler solution, double-quote the identifier in the query as sent to the server. Instead of

```
e.first_name as firstName
```

it should read

```
e.first_name as "firstName"
```

In PostgreSQL, double-quoting an identifier forces case-sensitivity.  Unquoted, it (mostly) follows the SQL standard and folds to a single case (albeit lower case where the standard is upper case).

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to how ( and if ) you configured your `NamingStrategy`

http://matthew.mceachen.us/blog/hibernate-naming-strategies-20.html

or

if you're using MySQL to weather or not you've enabled case sensitive table/column names http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html