# jpa non managed entities

Tags: java, jpa, orm, audit-logging

Let's say I have to fire a query like this:

```
Select primarykey, columnname, old_value, new_value from first_audit_log;

Select primarykey, columnname, old_value, new_value from second_audit_log;

Select primarykey, columnname, old_value, new_value from third_audit_log; ...so on
```

`audit_log` is not mapped as JPA enity to any class and I strictly can't create `n` number of classes for `n` number of `*_audit_logs`.

Using native query feature, how best I can map this to a generic class? Trying to SELECT NEW feature, but not sure... Hence any help is appreciated.

Comment: What persistence provider you are using? Eclipselink has ResultType hint that might help http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.2/org/eclipse/persistence/config/ResultType.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your audit logs tables share the same columns, you can create a view that "unifies" those tables and map a single Java class to that view. I believe you can, since you don't need to write updates, I guess.

As an alternative, using native queries would be a good choice.

**EDIT**:

1) If your audit logs are *already* views, you can create a view based on other views, if you don't want to create a mapping Java class for each of them. Just remember to add a dummy column that has value `1` if the row comes from the "first" audit log, `2` if it comes from the second, and so on, so you can set them apart.

2) In order to use native queries, assuming your persistence provider is Hibernate, you can do like in this example:

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("test");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();

Session sess = em.unwrap(Session.class); // <-- Use Hibernate-specific features
SQLQuery query = sess.createSQLQuery(
   "SELECT AVG(age) AS averageAge, AVG(salary) as averageSalary FROM persons");

query.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(MyResult.class));
MyResult result = (MyResult) query.list().get(0);
```

where `MyResult` is declared as follows:

```
public class MyResult {

    private BigDecimal averageAge;
    private BigDecimal averageSalary;

    public BigDecimal getAverageAge() {
        return averageAge;
    }
    public void setAverageAge(BigDecimal averageAge) {
        this.averageAge = averageAge;
    }
    public BigDecimal getAverageSalary() {
        return averageSalary;
    }
    public void setAverageSalary(BigDecimal averageSalary) {
        this.averageSalary = averageSalary;
    }

}
```

and the `persons` table is like this (MySQL syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE `persons` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `firstname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `age` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `salary` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

You can easily adapt this example to your needs, just replace `persons` and `MyResult` with what you want.

Comment: no ..auditlogs are already views...how to map to generic class using native queries?...i would like  to avoide Object[] paths

Comment: your seond option is better, but need to know how to map a custom class

Comment: Why don't you try to map to one of your custom classes? The docs doesn't say "resultClass" has to be managed.

Comment: I were wrong. I updated my answer: this seems the only way to do it using Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

The aliases in the sql query is automatically converted to upper case and its looking for the setter in Upper case as a result  org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException Exception is thrown. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

For instance, the below statement is looking for the setter ID instead of Id/id (Could not find setter for ID on class Data)

```
List<Data> result = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class) 
            .createSQLQuery("Select id as id from table") 
            .setParameter("day", date.getDayOfMonth()) 
            .setParameter("month", date.getMonthOfYear()) 
            .setParameter("year", date.getYear()) 
           .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Data.class))
           .list();

class Data {
  Integer id;

  public Integer getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(Integer id) {
   this.id = id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Forcing case sensitivity using "" worked for me... I found the answer in the following link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136225/resulttransformer-with-createsqlquery-forces-no-camelcase-in-entity-fields

Comment: I have another question what will happen to the session after this line: entityManager.unwrap(Session.class) ? Will the session be closed automatically or we have to explicitly close the session?